# Unable to push a commit due to missing LFS objects, after having utilized laravel shift to upgrade application to 6.x from 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, git-lfs

As the title suggests, I attempted a laravel shift on my project to go to 6.x from 5.8. I followed the changelog provided by the laravel shift branch in my project and made appropriate changes, and when I tried to commit and push changes, I received an error indicating that certain LFS upload objects were missing.

Error:
(missing) vendor/srmklive/paypal/tests/Mocks/samples/sample.pdf
(missing) vendor/srmklive/paypal/tests/Mocks/samples/sample2.pdf

However, when I checked the file path, the files are present and not missing or hidden.

Having received this error, I tried to fix it by running the git command to allow incomplete push.

```
git config lfs.allowincompletepush true
```

However, this did not fix my problem and I still received an error indicating that the files are missing.

Answer (score -1):

If you're encountering issues with Git LFS (Large File Storage) after upgrading your Laravel project using Laravel Shift, you might need to ensure that your Git LFS files are properly tracked and available. Here are some steps you can follow to resolve the issue:

**1.Check Git LFS Status:** Make sure that Git LFS is properly initialized and that the files are being tracked. Run the following commands in your project directory:

```
git lfs install
git lfs track "vendor/srmklive/paypal/tests/Mocks/samples/*.pdf"
```

The second command above is an example, and you need to specify the correct path based on your file structure.

**2.Commit and Push LFS Files:**
After initializing Git LFS, commit and push the LFS files to your repository:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Committing LFS files"
git push origin your-branch
```

**3.Check .gitattributes File:** Ensure that the .gitattributes file in your project includes proper LFS tracking rules. Open the file and verify that it has entries similar to:

```
vendor/srmklive/paypal/tests/Mocks/samples/*.pdf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

**4.Clean Local LFS Cache:** Try cleaning your local Git LFS cache and fetching the LFS files again:

```
git lfs clean
git lfs fetch
git lfs pull
```

**5.Update LFS Configuration:** Check your global Git LFS configuration and make sure it's correctly set:

```
git lfs env
```

Ensure that lfs.allowincompletepush is set to true.

**6.Git Hooks:** If you have any Git hooks that interact with LFS, review them to ensure they are not causing issues.

**7.Contact Laravel Shift Support:** If the issue persists, consider reaching out to Laravel Shift support. They might provide additional guidance or assistance specific to your Laravel Shift upgrade.